# Should app components have access to viewmodel?

Tags: android, validation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show password strength and validation on my app. I have separate app components such as `fun PasswordFieldTextComponent` in one AppComponents.kt file and I also have `SignupScreen.kt`. I am lost on how to access `OutlinedTextField` parameters in the `fun PasswordFieldTextComponent`. I have a `val passwordError` variable I need to access in `OutlinedTextField` which depends on
`val passwordError by viewModel.passwordError.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` of SignupScreen.kt. I don't think plain components should have viewmodels as parameters as that is only required in the screens such as SignupScreen.kt. What is the best practice to validate the `OutlinedTextField`? Where should validation occur? In the SignupScreen.kt or the AppComponent.kt file?

```
@Composable
fun PasswordTextFieldComponent(
    labelValue: String, painterResource: Painter,
    onTextSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    errorStatus: Boolean = false
) {
    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val password = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    val passwordVisible = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(componentShapes.small),
        label = { Text(text = labelValue) },
        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedBorderColor = Primary,
            focusedLabelColor = Primary,
            cursorColor = Primary,
            unfocusedContainerColor = BgColor
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
            localFocusManager.clearFocus()
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        value = password.value,
        onValueChange = {
            password.value = it
            onTextSelected(it)
        },
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(painter = painterResource, contentDescription = "")
        },
        trailingIcon = {

            val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                Icons.Filled.Visibility
            } else {
                Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
            }

            val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
            } else {
                stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
            }

            IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
            }

        },
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        isError = !errorStatus  || !passwordError.status
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)) {
        ConditionRow(condition = "Minimum 6 characters", check = passwordError.hasMinimum)
        ConditionRow(condition = "Has special character", check = passwordError.hasSpecialCharacter)
        ConditionRow(condition = "Has capitalized letter", check = passwordError.hasCapitalizedLetter)
    }
    }
```

SignupScreen.kt

```
 PasswordTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.password),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_lock),
                            onTextSelected = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.passwordError,

                        )
```

Comment: If validation has business logic, it should be in ViewModel. ViewModel should expose data to indicate the validation state and that should be used in the child composables. It is recommended to have viewmodel only at a screen level composable. Child composables can take data and event callbacks.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I am particularly not sure where to put `val passwordError` as OutlinedTextField is in AppComponents file (child composables), but this depends on `val passwordError by viewModel.passwordError.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`? If I put it in SignupScreen.kt I can't access it as a parameter in isError parameter of OutlinedTextField.